# Assembly x86 push the value of a register onto the stack

Tags: assembly, x86, shellcode

I'm working on a buffer overflow exercise and I have my connected client IP address available on the stack (ESP + 7C).

Is it possible to write a single instruction to push the value of the IP into the stack, so I can use it later?  I want my shellcode to be smaller in size; that's why I don't want to write multiple instructions to push its value.

Is this instruction ok? Would it push the value of ESP+7c onto the stack ?

```
PUSH [ESP+7c]
```

Comment: Yes it's logically fine, but you should use the proper syntax for hex numbers and you might need a size specifier, e.g. `push dword [esp+0x7c]` for nasm. Also be careful using `push` with `esp`-relative addresses since `push` obviously changes `esp`.

Comment: thanks yes exactly i did  PUSH DWORD PTR SS:[ESP+7C] however i can't see the value in the stack. I will give it another try

Comment: That is going to push the value that is in memory location ESP+0x7c, not the value “esp+0x7c”; if you want to do the latter, something like push eax; lea eax, [esp + 0x80]; xchg eax, [esp].

Comment: doing the following   
  
push eax; lea eax, [esp + 0x7C]; xchg eax, [esp]   
  
gives the below result:  
  
http://%14%FC/

Comment: After a `push eax`, you'd need `lea eax, [esp + 0x7c + 4]`.  That sounds like a silly idea unless you need to preserve the old value of EAX, though.  Just use `push dword ptr [esp + 0x7c]` or `push dword ptr [esp + 07Ch]` like a normal person., if you're using MASM syntax.